# Extending the list of keywords in eclipse for coloring

Tags: sql, eclipse

Occasionally I write `SQL` scripts and functions for `PostgreSQL` database. As any DB it has its own flavor of `SQL` with non-standard keywords which `Eclipse` naturally can't recognize and color as keywords (e.g. `CLUSTER`, `RETURNING`, etc). From the screenshot below it even looks like `Eclipse` can't detect that `varchar` is a type and colors it as a keyword.

[image]

I am trying to find ***a way to modify/extend the standard list of keywords, types*** etc. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL Editor doesn't provide such customization of keywords. But that would be a good enhancement request to place at bugs.eclipse.org ;)